# Making use of index in mysql join

Tags: mysql, join, indexing, query-optimization

I have a MySQL table T and there is an index on a column c1. My join query is as follows.

```
select something from T as t1 inner join T as t2 on ABS(t1.c1-t2.c1)<2;
```

I used explain to see whether MySQL uses index or not. It didn't use index for the above query. But it did use index for below query.

```
select something from T as t1 inner join T as t2 on t1.c1=t2.c1;
```

So how can make MySQL use index on the first query?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What data type is the c1 column?

Comment: @lke c1 is a float.

Comment: Please show us (1) the real query with ike's suggested revision, (2) `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`, (3) `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.  There is something subtle that may surface in one of these outputs.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the function call surrounding the `t2.c1` column in order to use the index on that column.

A query like this should work for you:

```
SELECT something
FROM T AS t1
INNER JOIN T AS t2 ON t2.c1 > (t1.c1 - 2) and t2.c1 < (t1.c1 + 2);
```

NOTE: This assume that you have an index on the `c1` column.

Comment: This might be not the same for non integers. You should use `t2.c1 > t1.c1 - 2 and t2.c1 < t1.c1 + 2` instead.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel thanks, I didn't even think of that! I'll update my answer.

Comment: None of the three queries using index but fastest one is( select something from T as t1 inner join T as t2 on ABS(t1.c1-t2.c1)<2;)

Comment: @Avinash142857 What is your server version?

Comment: @Avinash142857 I've just tested on MariaDB 10.0.9 with a 10K rows table (random floats from 0 to 100000). This query is like 50 to 100 times faster than the `ABS()` way.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.20, for Linux (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper

Comment: @PaulSpiegel Using amazon aws

Comment: If you have only a few dozen rows, the index is a waste of time.  The Optimizer realizes this, and simply scans the table.  (Hence, Paul's test worked, but (perhaps) Avinash's failed.)

Comment: @RickJames But I have 800K rows.